# dynamodb query: ValidationException: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have the following schema where I am basically just trying to have a table with `id` as primary key, and both `code` and `secondCode` to be global  secondary indexes to use to query the table.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "myDb" {
  name         = "myTable"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "id"

  attribute {
    name = "id"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "code"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "secondCode"
    type = "S"
  }

  global_secondary_index {
    name = "code-index" 
    hash_key = "code"
    projection_type = "ALL"
  }

  global_secondary_index {
    name = "second_code-index" 
    hash_key = "secondCode"
    projection_type = "ALL"
  }
}
```

When I try to look for one item by `code`

```
const toGet = Object.assign(new Item(), {
    code: 'code_456',
});

item = await dataMapper.get<Item>(toGet);
```

locally I get

`ValidationException: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid`

and on the deployed instance of the DB I get

`The provided key element does not match the schema`

I can see from the logs that the `key` is not being populated

```
Serverless: [AWS dynamodb 400 0.082s 0 retries] getItem({ TableName: 'myTable', Key: {} })
```

Here is the class configuration for `Item`

```
@table(getEnv('MY_TABLE'))
export class Item {
    @hashKey({ type: 'String' })
    id: string;

    @attribute({
        indexKeyConfigurations: { 'code-index': 'HASH' },
        type: 'String',
    })
    code: string;

    @attribute({
        indexKeyConfigurations: { 'second_code-index': 'HASH' },
        type: 'String',
    })
    secondCode: string;

    @attribute({ memberType: embed(NestedItem) })
    nestedItems?: Array<NestedItem>;
}

class NestedItem {
    @attribute()
    name: string;
    @attribute()
    price: number;
}
```

I am using https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js

Comment: Which SDK/Client are you using for the GetItem? It does not look like native DynamoDB client?

Comment: It seems you are having JS mapper, can you share your class configuration for `Item` also?

Comment: @LeeHannigan you are right, I am using data-mapper. I updated the post with the class configuration.

Comment: @AngularDebutant I looked at the repo you linked for the package, I think you need to use the `.query(...)` method with the `indexName` parameter to tell DynamoDB you want to use that secondary index. Usuallly in DynamoDB, `get` operations use the default keys (in your case, you'd use `get` for queries on `id`, and `query` for queries on indices.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi can I please ask how you figure that out? Because I cannot see that in the docs!

Comment: @AngularDebutant it's not very clear - if you look at the [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) reference, you'll see there's nowhere to supply an index name to actually use the index, whereas the [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation allows you to supply one. As for why DDB doesn't just automatically use the index. As for why you need to query this way, yo ucan read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGilardi! That actually fixed it. If you write it as an answer i'd approve it.

Comment: Cool, @AngularDebutant, just added the comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the repo you linked for the package, I think you need to use the `.query(...)` method with the `indexName` parameter to tell DynamoDB you want to use that secondary index. Usuallly in DynamoDB, `get` operations use the default keys (in your case, you'd use `get` for queries on `id`, and `query` for queries on indices).

Checking the docs, it's not very clear - if you look at the `GetItem` reference, you'll see there's nowhere to supply an index name to actually use the index, whereas the `Query` operation allows you to supply one. As for why you need to query this way, you can read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is due to calling a `GetItem` on an index, which is not possible. A `GetItem` must target a single item and an index can contain multiple items with the same key (unlike the base table), for this reason you can only use multi-item APIs on an index which are `Query` and `Scan`.